# Find files with capital letters before the extension and lowercase letters in the extension

Tags: command-line, scripts, files

I need to find files in remote location (/mnt/) and alert if a file name matches these criteria:

1. The file name must contain only capital letters or digits.
2. The file extension must contain only small letters.

The negative way also will work.

example:

if-file name contains small letters and/or extension contains capital letters

then- echo alert

Comment: Are other characters allowed  in the name (for example `-_0123456789`?

Comment: Please add a complete example of what you want to do instead of adding information bit by bit.

Comment: what if the filename has several dots in it? which part would you consider its extension? the "last letters after the last dot" ? (the usual way)

Comment: Will all the files be in one directory or can you also have subdirectories? Can you have files with no extension? Files with multiple "extensions" (`foo.bar.baz`)? Is the filesystem of the remote directory case sensitive?

Comment: give a try to [`pls`](https://github.com/Avinash-Raj/pls),  run this command on the directory where you want to search for files `pls -r '^[A-Z0-9]+\.[a-z]+$'`

Answer (score 9):

Use `find` to search for files:

```
find . -regex ".*/[A-Z0-9]+\.[a-z]+"
```

This performs the search in the current directory (`.`), recursively going through subdirectories as well.

- `[.*/]` covers the file path
- `[A-Z0-9]` stands for *every letter from A to Z* (including e.g. Å as mentioned by @vidarlo) and *every digit from 0 to 9*
- `+` matches the preceding character or expression one or multiple times
- `\.` is a literal dot
- `[a-z]` stands for *every letter from a to z*

For some special characters it might be necessary to use e.g. `[[:upper:]]` instead:

```
find . -regextype egrep -regex ".*/[[:upper:][:digit:]]+\.[[:lower:]]+"
```

#### Edited question

To combine `find`'s tests there's `-a` and `-o`, for your example this could help:

```
find /mnt/ \( -name "*[a-z]*.*" -o -name "*.*[A-Z]*" \) -exec echo {} +
```

Comment: GNU find version `4.4.2` struggles with case sensitivity such as `[A-Z]+` pattern matches upper and lowercase, with `-regex` or `-iregex` flags, because the engine underneath has its own case-sensitivity and or insensitivity enforcing system.  The two fight each other resulting in `[A-Z]+` sometimes capturing lowercase and uppercase, and sometimes only capturing uppercase.  `egrep` seems to not have this problem.

Answer (score 4):

Just with bash:

```bsh
shopt -s extglob nullglob

cd /mnt

# just print the "good" files
printf "%s\n" +([[:upper:][:digit:]]).+([[:lower:]])

# or, report on all files
for f in *; do
    if [[ $f == +([[:upper:][:digit:]]).+([[:lower:]]) ]]; then
        echo "OK: $f"
    else
        echo "**: $f"
    fi
done
```

See [Pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching) in the bash manual.

Comment: Thanks you @glenn jackman , i am getting an error message when i try to run the "report" section only :line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `do
line 1: `for f in *; do

Comment: The error message formatting does not work well in a comment. Ensure your file does not have CRLF line endings.

Comment: Hi @glenn jackman , can i run the "report on ail files" only on its own? i tried to test it in shellcheck and it gave me an error.

Comment: what error does shellcheck give you?

Comment: This is what I see, after adding the `#!` line and correcting the quotes for the printf format string: https://postimg.org/image/l0l2a5x09/

Comment: Worth noting that this doesn't recurse into subdirectories, contrary to the `find` based answers here. Which may or may not desirable depending on context. +1.

Answer (score 3):

### `find` command using a shellscript

Try if the following method with a find command and a shellscript works. You may modify

- the `find` command line and
- the shellscript (for example the output)

to fit exactly what you want.

```
find -type f -exec ./checker {} \; | sort
```

where `checker` contains

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
 echo "Usage: $0 <filename>"
 echo "Enter the file name as a parameter"
 exit
fi

inversvid="\0033[7m"
redback="\0033[1;37;41m"
resetvid="\0033[0m"

filnam=${1##*/}
name=${filnam%\.*}
upnam=${name^^}
ext=${filnam##*.}
loex=${ext,,}

if [ "${filnam^^}" == "$upnam" ]
then
 corrfile=$upnam
else
 corrfile="$upnam.$loex"
fi

if [ "$corrfile" == "$filnam" ]
then
 echo -e " good match: '$filnam'"
else
 echo -e "$redback bad match:  '$filnam' does not match '$corrfile' $resetvid"
fi
```

I made `checker` executable and call it locally. You may prefer to put it into `~/bin`, which brings it into `PATH` so that you can call it with `checker`.

```
chmod ugo+x checker
```

### Test

[image]

Comment: Thank you @sudodus , i will defiantly use this for problem analysis! i need a very simple script for monitoring software and therefore the reply to the findings most return from the same script, for example, if file name contains small letter and/or file extension contains capital letter then echo problem.

Comment: I improved the answer, It is worth testing the new version of the script.

Comment: Hi @sudodus when i am trying to run the script i am getting an error message: 
find -type f -exec ./checker {} \; | sort
find: `./checker': No such file or directory

Comment: @yarone, To run `./checker`: 1. Make it executable, `chmod ugo+x checker`; 2. Use a correct path, `./` means that it is in the current directory. You can use the full path, `/full-path-whatever-it-is/checker`; 3. You may prefer to create `~/bin` and  put `checker` into `~/bin`, which brings it into `PATH` so that you can call it with `checker` (after reboot). After that you can put all your own scripts and own executable programs into `~/bin` and run them (without reboot).

Comment: Hi @sudodus im running the ./checker from its current location, furthermore, ive tried to replace ./checker with another script that is working for sure and still the same error, im not sure what is the problem.

Comment: @yarone, 1. Please show which command line that you use, the whole command line; 2. Please run `ls -l` in the directory that you want to check; 3. Post the command line that you use and the result of `ls -l` by editing your original question and render it as code by indenting each line with 4 spaces.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68290/discussion-between-sudodus-and-yarone).